# Css flex - one item on the right, the other centered on the left space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm new to css and even newer to flex.
I couldn't find an answer, so I started a new one..
I have the following container and item:

```
  .container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .item {
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
```

This way I get 2 items on both sides (one left and one right).
I would like to know how to do the following:

1. The left item, will be on the left as before. From the point it ends, to the point the container ends - I with the right element to be centered.
2. The left item, will be on the left as before. The right item will be 10px left from the right end of the container.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you supply some HTML and perhaps a picture of what you want to achieve? This will help us identify what the issue is.

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this problem is using nested flexboxes. Get rid of the `display: block;` on `.item` - you can't mix flex and block display rules like that.

What you want to do is set up series of containers:

- one top level flex container
- two equally sized flex containers inside of the the top level container

Markup will look like this:

```
<main class="container">
  <section class="left-container">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </section>
  <section class="right-container">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </section>
</main>
```

In the CSS layer, you give the top-level `.container` flex and then `justify-content: space-between` which pushes the containers to the sides.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

In the two nested containers, you need to make them both `display: flex;` as well. Now you can control the positioning of your `.item` elements like you want. `align-items: center` controls the vertical axis so `.left-container` gets only that positioning while the right container gets `justify-content: center;` to control the vertical alignment.

```
.left-container {
  background-color: darkgray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
}

.right-container {
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Styling on the item is pretty simple - I just gave height and width for demo purposes. They aren't necessary. If you want to do precise tweaks, use `margin` on `.item` to push slightly from these standards.

```
.item {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

[image]

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/PmLyNM

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer! was really helpful.

Comment: Thanks - glad it helped. If the answer solved your problem, be sure to mark it as the accepted answer so others can follow the solution.